# JpaRepostory existsXXX method don't working properly

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to check is user with a specified id and token exists. Tokens are stored in `@ElementCollection` set. I tried to write a derived query method in my repository like this:

```java
boolean existsByIdAndTokensContains(long id, String token);
```

But that isn't working (returns `false` for right input values).

When I tried to specify query explicitly it start working right:

```java
@Query("select (count(u) > 0) from users as u where u.id = :id and :token member of u.tokens")
```

The most strange that Hibernate logs are looking similar for both queries:

For the derived query:

```
/* select
    generatedAlias0.id 
from
    users as generatedAlias0 
where
    (
        generatedAlias0.id=:param0 
    ) 
    and (
        :param1 member of generatedAlias0.tokens 
    ) */ select
        userentity0_.id as col_0_0_ 
    from
        users userentity0_ 
    where
        userentity0_.id=? 
        and (
            ? in (
                select
                    tokens1_.token 
                from
                    users_tokens tokens1_ 
                where
                    userentity0_.id=tokens1_.user_id
            )
        ) limit ?
```

For the explicit query:

```
/* select
    (count(u) > 0) 
from
    users as u 
where
    u.id = :id 
    and :token member of u.tokens */ select
        count(userentity0_.id)>0 as col_0_0_ 
    from
        users userentity0_ 
    where
        userentity0_.id=? 
        and (
            ? in (
                select
                    tokens1_.token 
                from
                    users_tokens tokens1_ 
                where
                    userentity0_.id=tokens1_.user_id
            )
        )
```

And when I tried to query generated query, result contained the right user.

What am I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you need to implement an [Attribute Converter](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/) to convert the id into a Boolean. This way it will know how to map a not null Id to a true value.

Comment: I think if this was would be a problem I had got an exception while calling this method because I already tried to declare and call a method that returns boolean with a query that returns an entity, in `@Query` annotation.

Comment: `select (count(u) > 0) from users...` would return a Boolean not an entity

Comment: I know, but I said about a query like `select u from users...` in previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

For my `Set` of tokens:

```java
@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "token", nullable = false)
@CollectionTable(name = "users_tokens", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "token"}))
private final Set<String> tokens;
```

Works the similar query but without `Contains`:

```java
boolean existsByIdAndTokens(long id, String token);
```

I don't know is it a bug, but this works for me.